# T-SQL Select from JSON returns JSON text is not properly formatted

Tags: json, t-sql

Using a stored procedure in SQL Server 2016 (included below) I need to make a select from the nested JSON output from a remote file, but at my initial `SELECT *` I already have issues since the server returns that the JSON text is not properly formatted:

> JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character 'A' is found at position 0.

The T-SQL script I use:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE wget 
    @url VARCHAR(255), 
    @payload NVARCHAR(max) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @op TABLE (op nvarchar(max))
    DECLARE @c varchar(1000) = N'powershell.exe -noprofile -executionpolicy bypass'
    + N'-command (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "'+@url+'" -UseBasicParsing).content'

    INSERT INTO @op 
        EXEC xp_cmdshell @c

    SELECT @payload = STRING_AGG(op, '') 
    FROM @op
END


DECLARE @jsn nvarchar(max)
EXEC wget @url = 'https://<URL-WITH-JSON-DATA>',
          @payload = @jsn output

SELECT * 
FROM OPENJSON (@jsn, N'$')
```

2 array examples of the JSON file:

```
[
    {
      "Localnumber":"2931",
      "Name":"Some Name",
      "Description":null,
      "Email":"mail@domain.dk",
      "PhoneNumbers":[
         {
            "Number":"98765432",
            "LineName":null,
            "BelongsTo":"2931",
            "GotoLocalNumber":null
         },
         {
            "Number":"23456789",
            "LineName":null,
            "BelongsTo":"2931",
            "GotoLocalNumber":null
         },
         {
            "Number":"34567890",
            "LineName":null,
            "BelongsTo":"2931",
            "GotoLocalNumber":null
         }
      ],
      "Phones":[
         {
            "LocalNumber":"200000",
            "Name":null,
            "Type":21,
            "MAC":null,
            "BelongsTo":"2931",
            "description":"Myfone"
         },
         {
            "LocalNumber":"200048",
            "Name":null,
            "Type":8,
            "MAC":"20470396",
            "BelongsTo":"2931",
            "description":"Mobil (23456789)"
         },
         {
            "LocalNumber":"200084",
            "Name":null,
            "Type":23,
            "MAC":null,
            "BelongsTo":"2931",
            "description":"Microsoft Teams"
         },
         {
            "LocalNumber":"200125",
            "Name":null,
            "Type":8,
            "MAC":"23214202",
            "BelongsTo":"2931",
            "description":"Mobil (23456789)"
         }
      ],
      "Info":[
         {
            "Type":0,
            "Label":null,
            "Value":null
         }
      ],
      "Department":null
   },
   {
      "Localnumber":"2931",
      "Name":"Some Name",
      "Description":null,
      "Email":"mail@domain.dk",
      "PhoneNumbers":[
         {
            "Number":"98765432",
            "LineName":null,
            "BelongsTo":"2931",
            "GotoLocalNumber":null
         },
         {
            "Number":"23456789",
            "LineName":null,
            "BelongsTo":"2931",
            "GotoLocalNumber":null
         },
         {
            "Number":"34567890",
            "LineName":null,
            "BelongsTo":"2931",
            "GotoLocalNumber":null
         }
      ],
      "Phones":[
         {
            "LocalNumber":"200000",
            "Name":null,
            "Type":21,
            "MAC":null,
            "BelongsTo":"2931",
            "description":"Myfone"
         },
         {
            "LocalNumber":"200048",
            "Name":null,
            "Type":8,
            "MAC":"20470396",
            "BelongsTo":"2931",
            "description":"Mobil (23456789)"
         },
         {
            "LocalNumber":"200084",
            "Name":null,
            "Type":23,
            "MAC":null,
            "BelongsTo":"2931",
            "description":"Microsoft Teams"
         },
         {
            "LocalNumber":"200125",
            "Name":null,
            "Type":8,
            "MAC":"23214202",
            "BelongsTo":"2931",
            "description":"Mobil (23456789)"
         }
      ],
      "Info":[
         {
            "Type":0,
            "Label":null,
            "Value":null
         }
      ],
      "Department":null
   }
]
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: SQL Server can't consume invalid JSON, if the source is invalid, you need to fix the process that is creating that source.

Comment: Hi @Larnu .. The JSON is valid (verified), and delivered from a large company where it is used by thousands of customers on a daily basis, so I doubt that the JSON is the root source of the failure, more that I am doing the select wrong.

Comment: Then SQL Server would not tell you it's invalid... Perhaps what you're doing to consume the data on SQL Server is the problem. `xp_cmdshell` is limited to non-`MAX` lengths, for example, so if the JSON is more than 4,000 characters it'll be truncated. If you want to connect to a webservice from SQL Server you should be using CLR objects.

Comment: Have you done any [basic debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) of your stored procedure? At very least selected the raw data from `@op`?

Comment: The JSON you've given, however, does not produce the error: [dB<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c77480e4fbe15a836b39165cc153606d)

Comment: Clearly the value of @jsn actually begins with an A and is invalid JSON

Comment: @Larnu I was not aware of the limitation of `xp_cmdshell` and I think that is the problem, the data content is to large .. I think I will concentrate on looking into CLR objects to solve this issue, thanks .. feel free to post answer if you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to import the JSON into a table with a varchar(MAX) from JScript server side:

```
Response.CacheControl = "no-cache"
Response.Expires = -1
Response.CodePage = 65001
Response.CharSet = "UTF-8"

var objSrvHTTP;
objSrvHTTP = Server.CreateObject ("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0");
objSrvHTTP.open ("GET","<%URL_TO_JSON_DATA%>", false);
objSrvHTTP.send ();
Response.ContentType = "application/json";
```

And then query the stored JSON from table using below query:

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @json = (SELECT PHONE_DATA FROM EFP_JSON WHERE ID = 1)

SELECT PhoneNumber
FROM EFP_PhoneNumberSeries
WHERE REPLACE(PhoneNumber, ' ', '') NOT IN (
    SELECT PhoneNumbers.Number
    FROM OPENJSON(@json)
    WITH (   
        Localnumber VARCHAR(50) '$.Localnumber',
        Name VARCHAR(50) '$.Name',
        Email VARCHAR(50) '$.Email',
        PhoneNumbers nvarchar(max) '$.PhoneNumbers' AS JSON,
        Phones nvarchar(max) '$.Phones' AS JSON       
        ) as UserInfo
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(PhoneNumbers)
    WITH(
        Number nvarchar(100) '$.Number',
        LineName nvarchar(100) '$.LineName',
        GotoLocalNumber nvarchar(100) '$.GotoLocalNumber',
        BelongsTo nvarchar(100) '$.BelongsTo'
        )  as PhoneNumbers
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(Phones)
    WITH(
        description nvarchar(100) '$.description'
        ) as description
    ) 
AND REPLACE(PhoneNumber, ' ', '') NOT IN ('12345678','98765432')
AND (REPLACE(PhoneNumber, ' ', '') LIKE '1234%' OR REPLACE(PhoneNumber, ' ', '') LIKE '98765%');
```